# ansible-galaxy error: API server not found

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to install an ansible role through ansible-galaxy.  I run the command

```
ansible-galaxy install nickhammond.logrotate
```

and get the response:

```
ERROR! The API server (https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/) is not responding, please try again later.
```

I've tried updating my version of ansible (1.9.1, 1.9.2, 2.0.1) but nothing seems to fix the problem.  I can get to the API server, by just going to https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/ in my web browser.  Any ideas why galaxy doesn't seem to be working for me?

Comment: The proxy setup in your (corporate) browser might differ from the one on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you use proxy, set evnironment "https_proxy" as "http://ip:port" format. not "ip:port" format.

```
export https_proxy=http://ip:port
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For me ansible was installed by `pip`and I had to uninstall it first:

```
pip uninstall ansible
```

Then I reinstalled it with `brew`

```
brew install ansible
```

After this it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced same issue and also I was behind corporate proxy as well.'-c' option helped me to proceed further.

`-c, --ignore-certs    Ignore SSL certificate validation errors.`

Comment: A self-signed certificate error message might mask that the proxy policy is in effect. Do you need add the URL to an allow-list?

Answer (score 0):

AHA!  Apparently I need wget in order for ansible-galaxy to work.  I used macports to install wget and ansible-galaxy install worked like a charm!

Comment: why do you need `wget` to run `ansible-galaxy install nickhammond.logrotate`?